# How to import and use stopwords list from NLTK?

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, nltk, stop-words

I already imported `stopwords` from `nltk.corpus`, but I get `STOPWORDS is not defined` error. Below is my code:

```py
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
#Create stopword list:
stopwords = set(STOPWORDS)
```

The above gives the following error:

```
NameError: name 'STOPWORDS' is not defined
```

Comment: You have already imported `stopwords`; what exactly are you trying to set in the next line, and what is `STOPWORDS` (which is nowhere defined indeed)?

Comment: How to define, I am new in ML. I want to remove stopword from data set, so I used nltk to remove the same

Answer (score 1):

The very first time of using `stopwords` from the `NLTK` package, you need to execute the following code, in order to **download** the list to your device:

```py
import nltk
nltk.download('stopwords')
```

Then, every time you need to use `stopwords`, you can simply **load** them from the package. For example, to load the English `stopwords` list, you can use the following:

```py
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
stop_words = list(stopwords.words('english'))
```

You can even **extend** the list, if you want to, as shown below (**Note**: if `stopwords.words()` returns an object of `set` type, then the conversion to `list`—as shown above— is required, in order to call the `extend()` method on the `stop_words` object):

```
stop_words.extend(["best", "item", "fast"])
```

To **remove** stop words from text, you can use the below (have a look at the various available tokenizers [here](https://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.tokenize.html) and [here](https://www.nltk.org/howto/tokenize.html)):

```
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
word_tokens = word_tokenize(text)
clean_word_data = [w for w in word_tokens if w.lower() not in stop_words]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to download the right stopwords you want to use.
For example if you simply want to print the stopwords which are used in english:

```
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
nltk.download('stopwords')
print(stopwords.words('english'))
```

This should give you the output of english stopwords like `'i', 'me', 'my', 'myself', 'we', 'our', 'ours', 'ourselves',....]`