# how to import/download with the stopwords in the NLTK?

Tags: python, python-3.x, nltk

I downloaded nltk package via pip , but when I run my code , i get a messeage, "Resource stopwords not found, please use the NLTK downloader to obtain the resource ...."

```
from nltk.corpus import stopwords

stop_words = set(stopwords.words('english'))
```

Do I need any other packages installed, my understanding is stopwords is included in the NLTK package and should be available once i run pip install NLTK.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Corpora/stopwords not found when import nltk library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41610543/corpora-stopwords-not-found-when-import-nltk-library)

Comment: FYI, [this](https://www.nltk.org/data.html) authoritative source is the *first result* when you google `nltk stopwords download`. PLEASE do at least some **basic** research before asking here.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to import and use stopwords list from NLTK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70698947/how-to-import-and-use-stopwords-list-from-nltk)