# How to get bag of words and term frequency in text format using Sklearn?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, nlp, corpus, countvectorizer

I would like to print out the list of words (i.e., bag of words) for each document in a coprus and their respective term frequency (in text format), using Sklearn's `CountVectorizer`. How could I achieve that?

Here is my code:

```py
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer  

#instantiate vectorizer
vectorizer=CountVectorizer()   

#Document creation 
document1='this is a sunny day';document2= 'today is a very very very pleasant day and we have fun fun fun';document3= 'this is an amazin experience'

#list 
list_of_words= [document1,document2,document3]

#bag of words
bag_of_words = vectorizer.fit(list_of_words)

#verify vocabulary of repeated word 
print (vectorizer.vocabulary_.get('very')) 

print (vectorizer.vocabulary_.get('fun'))

#transform
bag_of_words=vectorizer.transform(list_of_words)

print(bag_of_words)>>>>
(0, 3) 1 (0, 7) 1 (0, 9) 1 (0, 10) 1 (1, 2) 1 (1, 3) 1 (1, 5) 3 (1, 6) 1 (1, 7) 1 (1, 8) 1 (1, 11) 1 (1, 12) 3 (1, 13) 1 (2, 0) 1 (2, 1) 1 (2, 4) 1 (2, 7) 1 (2, 10) 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.get_feature_names()` to get the list of words and `.toarray()` method to get the frequency of each term. Using Pandas `DataFrame`, you can export both in a `.csv` file or your console. The `stopwords` list provided by `nltk` can optionally be used to remove any `stopwords` from the documents (to extend the current list with more stop words, please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70712697/17865804)).

### Example:

```py
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer  
import pandas as pd
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import stopwords

# You need to run this only once, in order to download the stopwords list
nltk.download('stopwords') 

# Load the stopwords list
stop_words_list = stopwords.words('english')

# The documents 
document1='Hope you have a pleasant day. Have fun.'
document2= 'Today is a very pleasant day and we will have fun fun fun'
document3= 'This event has been amazing. We had a lot of fun the whole day'

# List of documents
list_of_documents= [document1, document2, document3]

# Instantiate CountVectorizer
cv = CountVectorizer(stop_words=stop_words_list)

# Fit and transform
cv_fit = cv.fit_transform(list_of_documents)
word_list = cv.get_feature_names()
count_list = cv_fit.toarray()

# Create a dataframe with words and their respective frequency 
# Each row represents a document starting from document1
df = pd.DataFrame(data=count_list, columns=word_list)

# Print out the df
print(df)

# Optionally, save the df to a csv file
df.to_csv("bag_of_words.csv")
```

Output:

[image: Bag of words]

To output the term frequency of the entire corpus (i.e., to summarise the results from all documents), you can use the below (in addition to the example above):

```py
import numpy as np

d = dict(zip(word_list, np.asarray(cv_fit.sum(axis=0))[0]))
sorted_d = dict(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda item: item[1], reverse=True))
print(sorted_d)

# Optionally, create a DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data=sorted_d, orient='index')
print(df)
df.to_csv("total_freq.csv")
```

Output:

[image: Total Frequency Results]